# Bullet and regular text styles in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to make a PowerPoint template. I am editing the master slides to build the different layouts I need.

However, I did not manage to create a text placeholder that would set the style for 'regular text' and 'lists'. It only works for list, albeit with a small trick.

I could try to create a first line as regular text, and the rest with my list style but it does not work

[image]

**This is what I want.** Regular text on the left, but if I want to make a list in that placeholder, it'll start with an indented green checkmark, then orange square, etc.

But alas, it does not work. It creates a default style list for the 1st level, and for the next ones too while keeping the bullet color (????)

[image]

---

At first, I tried to just set the list style, and I was thinking to simply say "this line is not a list" to have regular text. Unfortunately, doing this does not change de "Before text" indentation minus hanging (it will stay at the same level as the bullet)

For example, here's the master slide with the style list I want:
[image]

And here's the result when starting to use the layout and remove the list style of the first line

[image]

So I'm kinda lost on how to properly set default text style, and list style...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky to explain in writing but I will give it a go.

The text placeholder for all the Slaves is controlled and formatted in your Slide Master - the top slide in the Masters panel.

You have 9 available style slots to control through the 'Control' placeholder. Working with a default presentation you will have all slots with a bullet - the bullet holds the key to Tab content hierarchy, meaning you can increase and decrease your indent styles via the Tab/Shift Tab etc. if you create a style that has no bullet you must use the Menu ribbon indent to control the action.

I always start the sequence with a L1 Bullet, then L2 Bullet, then a Subhead (bold with a smaller space after, then body text. (this can include different sizes or colours if required)

You can repeat the sequence with a larger text or a second hierarchy sequence.

You can also create Masters that can work independently in the same way but can only be used using the the selected Slave.

Do you understand the way to create the indent sequence method in the Slide Master?

You need to set the paragraph indent to Hanging, this will push the text to line up with the first line indent [image: paragraph control screenshot]

I found a site which has download example of how this type of Body text heavy template can work.

https://www.duarte.com/resources/slidedocs-visual-documents/

Give it a go and I will check back later.